# How to Django models

Tags: mysql, django, performance, django-models

I am exploring Django with MySQL & have a few things that I wanted to discuss -

1. How can I add an index (on some field)? Can I do it through the Django Model Layer?
2. If I want to migrate some old data into these new DB tables/models, will I have to write some script myself or does Django provide schema to schema mapping tools?
3. If I need to change the schema for the existing Django Models, then what's the easiest way to do this? I know this depends on my schema but is it as simple as create a new column & run `python manage.py syncdb` ?
4. Lastly how do I profile MySQL db of all the queries I run from Django Models? I am looking for something like `DEBUG=True and TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True` kind of solution, where I'll get the query performance (runtime etc.) on the browser.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please ask one question at once!

Comment: @Torok then there'll be one too many questions & no one point of reference... This way I (& probably others) can come back to just this page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I add an index (on some field)? Can I do it through the Django Model Layer?

You can. Take a look at the [`Field.db_index`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-index) option.

> If I want to migrate some old data into these new DB tables/models, will I have to write some script myself or does Django provide schema to schema mapping tools?

Django does not have a built in tool to do data migration. For migrating existing data you will have to write a custom script. This *may* be possible using an external migration tool (such as South, see below) but I haven't tried it.

> Lastly If I need to change the schema for the existing Django Models, then what's the easiest way to do this? I know this depends on my schema but is it as simple as create a new column & run python manage.py syncdb ?

Use a migration tool. [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) is one of the popular and effective ones out there. There are others too. Using a tool will make your life much more easier for many reasons. For e.g. `syncdb` will not add new columns, only new tables.

> How do I profile MySQL db of all the queries I run from Django Models? I am looking for something like DEBUG=True and TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True kind of solution, where I'll get the query performance (runtime etc.) on the browser.

One of the ways to accomplish this is to use this classic [Django snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/93/). Using the snippet you can append statistics about the queries fired to render a page to the bottom of the page if `DEBUG` is set.

**Update**

Another way to display the debug information is to use the [django-debug-toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar). Thanks [@diegueus9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150647/diegueus9).

Comment: i recommend http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar for profile sql queries.

Comment: @thanks manoj & others. The answer(s) were a big help. Marked the only & correct answer :)